# I want to add delete option for table

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table which is fetched from MySQL database. I want to add delete options for every row that has to be removed both in server and client side. Can anyone give the steps to do delete option in PHP and MySQL?

Comment: Please put a little more effort into your questions. I don't know why I should bother answering if you can't be bothered to even spell check your posts. Also, what have you done? Have you written any code yourself, even non-working code?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this pseudo code would be able to help you out

1. Print button that contains the id of
   the row
2. When user clicks on the button post/get
   it to your .php
3. SQL Query: Delete from table where
   id = $id_you_got_from_button

Comment: i wann to delete from user that has to be delete in server also...i didnt get how i can delete the files